# how to split rdd elements by tabs and lines containing text and numbers in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a text file which is like the following

```
87687   564    A eats apple   10
76577   324    B plays Ball   7 
54325   654    C has Cat      9
```

I want the following output for `rdd.take(10)`

```
['87687', '564', 'A eats apple', '10']
['76577', '324', 'B plays Ball', '7'] 
['54325', '654', 'C has Cat', '9']
```

I tried the following code

```
rdd=mydata.map(lambda mydata: mydata.split("\t"))
rdd.take(10)
```

And I am getting this

```
[['87687', '564', 'A eats apple', '10'],
['76577', '324', 'B plays Ball', '7'], 
['54325', '654', 'C has Cat', '9']]
```

how do I get rid of the commas and the extra bracket. I was searching by "how to convert list of lists to multiple lists in pyspark" but I think that was not the right question most probably. trying to learn Spark, please help!

Comment: You can getting the correct output actually. You cannot store multiple lists in one variable without it being a list of lists right?

Comment: @Tanzin , There are no commas and brackets inside an RDD, those just appear when you print/display in an output console..  read/experiment more with Spark, this qn need revision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the display is correct, there are 3 elements in rdd, it is the operator `take()` which converts the elements into a list, to display it line and in column convert rdd to a dataframe